# Pointer Dequeue - pointer training

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to set up a double ended queue of pointers in C. 
So far I have the push functions working and tested. My problems seems to be with popping entries at both ends.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dequeue.h"

dequeue* dequeue_create()
{
    return NULL;
}
void dequeue_push_front(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
    dequeue* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    if((*dq) == NULL)
    {
        (*dq) = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((*dq)->next == NULL)
        {
            (*dq)->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev   = (*dq);

        }
        else
        {

            dequeue* tmp_it  = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
            tmp_it = (*dq)->next;
            while(tmp_it->next != NULL)
            {
                tmp_it = tmp_it->next;

            }
            tmp_it->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev    = tmp_it;

        }
    }
}

void dequeue_push_back(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
    dequeue* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->prev=NULL;
    if((*dq) == NULL)
    {
        (*dq) = tmp;
    }
    else
    {

        if ((*dq)->prev == NULL)
        {
            (*dq)->prev = tmp;
            tmp->next   = (*dq);

        }
        else
        {
            dequeue* tmp_it  = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
            tmp_it = (*dq)->prev;
            while(tmp_it->prev != NULL)
            {
                tmp_it = tmp_it->prev;
            }
            tmp_it->prev = tmp;
            tmp->next    = tmp_it;

        }
    }
}

int dequeue_pop_front(dequeue** dq)
{
    dequeue* tmp_get = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    int output = 0;

    if((*dq)->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("\ndqnext==null\n");
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_get = (*dq);
        while(tmp_get->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp_get= tmp_get->next;
            output = tmp_get->data;
        }
        tmp_get=tmp_get->prev;
        free(tmp_get->next);
        tmp_get->next=NULL;
    }
    return output;
}

int dequeue_pop_back(dequeue** dq)
{
    dequeue* tmp_get = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    int output = 0;

    if((*dq)->prev == NULL)
    {
        printf("\ndqprev==null\n");
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_get = (*dq);
        while(tmp_get->prev != NULL)
        {

            output = tmp_get->data;
            tmp_get= tmp_get->prev;

        }
        free(tmp_get);
        tmp_get=NULL;
    }
    return output;
}
```

dequeue.h:

```
#ifndef dequeue_H
#define dequeue_H

struct _dequeue_ {
  struct _dequeue_* next;
  struct _dequeue_* prev;
  int data;
};

typedef struct _dequeue_ dequeue;

dequeue* dequeue_create();
void dequeue_destroy(dequeue** queue);

int dequeue_pop_front(dequeue** dq);
void dequeue_push_front(dequeue** dq, int data);

int dequeue_pop_back(dequeue** dq);
void dequeue_push_back(dequeue** dq, int data);

#endif  /* dequeue_H */
```

main.c:

```
int main()
{
    dequeue* dq = dequeue_create();

    dequeue_push_front(&dq, 1);
    dequeue_push_back(&dq, 2);
    dequeue_push_front(&dq, 3);
    for (int cnt = 1; cnt <=4; cnt++)
    {
        printf("FINAL=%d ", dequeue_pop_front(&dq));
    }


    //TODO : dequeue_destroy(&dq);

    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty new to pointers, that's what appears to be my problem.

What I am trying to do in the pop-functions is iterating over the pointers to reach the last one and freeing this last pointer. But it seems that it is not freeing the pointer. Tried several different ways now, but none of the seem to work, could it be that the way I have set up the push functions it is not possible to free the pointers?

Any help very appreciated.
cheers

Comment: I don't get why you're calling `malloc()` inside pop. This is leading to memory leaks in your code.

Comment: I thought about using tmp_get as tmp pointer. Fixed this to dequeue* tmp_get = (*dq); and removed it in the elses.

Comment: upvote for (almost) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hints before digging into the actual problem:

- in dequeue.c, the first #include should be that for dequeue.h, because this is a systematic way to make sure, dequeue.h includes everything itself needs.
- the struct *dequeue* should just be called dequeue. (The later typedef can use the same name - no problem here)

And then, there is some misconception: Your _dequeue_s are NODES of a dequeue but not a dequeue itself. So, you should have two structs:

```
struct dequeue_node {
        struct dequeue_node * next;
        struct dequeue_node * prev;
        int data;
};

struct dequeue {
        struct dequeue_node * frst;
        struct dequeue_node * last;
        size_t size;
};
```

Calling the entry frst (and not first) is my personal style, it makes it 4 characters long like next/prev/last/size, but you can call it first if you like. size is not needed but allows for O(1) retrieval of the size of the dequeue.

This way, you don't have to walk over the entire dequeue to find it's end.

So, now your actual problem:

When creating the first node, dequeue_push_front doesn't initialize tmp->prev (and dequeue_push_back doesn't initialize tmp->next). So, you dequeue is in an illegal state from the start.

Then, when I think about "front", I think about "first" and assume there to be a next. So, pretty much, you're swapping the meaning of next and prev. Assuming this one:

```
                       a               b               c
                +-------------+ +-------------+ +-------------+
                | next = b    | | next = c    | | next = NULL |
                | prev = NULL | | prev = a    | | prev = b    |
                +-------------+ +-------------+ +-------------+
```

I would call a "first" and c "last". But dequeue_push_front tried so add one element right of c in this ascii art.

Given you're naming, the push functions seem to be correct (except for the point stated above).

The pop functions now have an error that has been noted by <s>s.b. who deleted his post again</s> Ben Wainwright (he edited, which was shown as post deletion). You check for (*dp)->next/prev == NULL and if that is true, you bail out, but you should delete the node. So for dequeue_pop_front (in your implementation):

```
if ((*dq)->next == NULL) {
    dequeue * tmp = (*dq);
    output = tmp->data;
    (*dq) = (*dq)->prev;
    if ((*dq)) {
            (*dq)->next = NULL;
    }
    free(tmp);
} else {
    ...
```

and in pop_back vice versa.

The rest of the problems are inefficiencies and memory leaks, for the latter you should learn to use http://valgrind.org/ to find them, and for the first, you should always ask yourself, weather a statement can be moved out of a loop, like here: (again from dequeue_pop_front):

```
    while(tmp_get->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp_get= tmp_get->next;
        output = tmp_get->data; // this can be moved out
    }
```

The output variable will be constantly overwritten, until the loop ends, so, put it out:

```
    while(tmp_get->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp_get= tmp_get->next;
    }
    output = tmp_get->data; // this can be moved out
```

So, the finalized dequeue.c (but you should really do the change with dequeue & dequeue_node):

```
dequeue* dequeue_create()
{
    return NULL;
}
void dequeue_push_front(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
    dequeue* tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    tmp->prev=NULL;
    if((*dq) == NULL)
    {
        (*dq) = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        if ((*dq)->next == NULL)
        {
            (*dq)->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev   = (*dq);

        }
        else
        {

            dequeue* tmp_it  = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
            tmp_it = (*dq)->next;
            while(tmp_it->next != NULL)
            {
                tmp_it = tmp_it->next;

            }
            tmp_it->next = tmp;
            tmp->prev    = tmp_it;

        }
    }
}

void dequeue_push_back(dequeue** dq, int data)
{
    dequeue* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    tmp->prev=NULL;
    if((*dq) == NULL)
    {
        (*dq) = tmp;
    }
    else
    {

        if ((*dq)->prev == NULL)
        {
            (*dq)->prev = tmp;
            tmp->next   = (*dq);

        }
        else
        {
            dequeue* tmp_it  = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
            tmp_it = (*dq)->prev;
            while(tmp_it->prev != NULL)
            {
                tmp_it = tmp_it->prev;
            }
            tmp_it->prev = tmp;
            tmp->next    = tmp_it;

        }
    }
}

int dequeue_pop_front(dequeue** dq)
{
    dequeue* tmp_get = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    int output = 0;

    if((*dq)->next == NULL)
    {
        dequeue * tmp = (*dq);
        output = tmp->data;
        (*dq) = (*dq)->prev;
        if ((*dq)) {
                (*dq)->next = NULL;
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_get = (*dq);
        while(tmp_get->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp_get= tmp_get->next;
            output = tmp_get->data;
        }
        tmp_get=tmp_get->prev;
        free(tmp_get->next);
        tmp_get->next=NULL;
    }
    return output;
}

int dequeue_pop_back(dequeue** dq)
{
    dequeue* tmp_get = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
    int output = 0;

    if((*dq)->prev == NULL)
    {
        dequeue * tmp = (*dq);
        output = tmp->data;
        (*dq) = (*dq)->next;
        if ((*dq)) {
                (*dq)->prev = NULL;
        }
        free(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_get = (*dq);
        while(tmp_get->prev != NULL)
        {

            output = tmp_get->data;
            tmp_get= tmp_get->prev;

        }
        free(tmp_get);
        tmp_get=NULL;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## The Pushes

```
dequeue_push_front(&dq, 1);
```

> NULL <- middle (1) -> NULL

`dq` is pointing to the middle node

```
dequeue_push_front(&dq, 2);
```

> NULL <- middle (1) <-> right (2) -> NULL

`dq` is still pointing to the middle node because your code only changes it if `dq` is passed in as `NULL`

> NULL <- left (3) <-> middle (1) <-> right (2) -> NULL

`dq` is *still* pointing to the middle node for the same reason

## The Pops

Lets follow your pop code:

```
 tmp_get = (*dq);
 while(tmp_get->next != NULL)
 {
     tmp_get= tmp_get->next;
     output = tmp_get->data;
 }
 tmp_get=tmp_get->prev;
 free(tmp_get->next);
 tmp_get->next=NULL;
```

This results in the following state:

> NULL <- left (3) <-> middle (1) -> NULL

`dq` is *still* pointing at the middle node. The next, and *every other time the function is executed*

```
if((*dq)->next == NULL)
```

Will evaluate to true, resulting in no further changes.

## Other Issues

As noted in the comments, there is a memory leak inside your pop function. See below:

```
dequeue* tmp_get = malloc(sizeof(struct _dequeue_));
...
tmp_get = (*dq);
```

`malloc()` is called, allocating `sizeof(struct _dequeue_)` bytes of memory. A pointer is returned, and assigned to the variable tmp_get. You then overwrite this pointer with a different pointer, meaning there is now a block of allocated memory that you are unable to access or free. I can't see any reason why you need to allocate this memory in the first place.