# Deleting Linked LIst in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I just stuck with the problem couple of hours, trying to find where my code breaks. I know how to delete linked list but something doesn't work.

First it is a very simple struct with a dataype of int and 2 struct *next and *prev.

```
struct _list_{ 
    struct _list_ *next;
    struct _list_ *prev;
    float distance;
}
```

Now i am making a push_front function and it works great. I get the result that i am looking for. But now i am making pop_front function and something is missing.

The function should return the distance and then remove that list from the linked list but i can't make it do it.

here is the code that i wrote

```
int pop_front(list** header)
{
  float number = (*header)->data;
  list *head = *header;
  list *remove = head;

  // This should check if the pointer is pointing at the first element
  while (head->prev != NULL) {
    head = head->prev;
  }

  if (head) {
    head = head->next;
    free(remove);
    remove = head;
    remove->prev = NULL;
    //if i remove the code below then i get this error 
    //*** Error in `./double_ended_queue.out': double free or 
    //corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001d5a050 ***
    //Pop up: 3 pointer: 3 Aborted (core dumped)
    *header = *remove;
    //And with this code i get a Segmentation fault (core dumped
    return number;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

P.S. checked all the linked list question here and none helped.

Comment: the `delete` is a reserved keyword. Please rename it.

Comment: Either this is C and then you can use a variable named `delete` (although I would not recommend it), or it is not and then you should not. Either way, using *both* language tags is wrong.

Comment: sry removed the c++ tag

Comment: this looks wonky. `*remove = head; free(remove); remove=head`. aren't you freeing what `head` points at, and then immediately using `head` again?

Comment: it should show to the next element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you all getting this homework from? The API sux. Here, someone else did have almost the same homework (link pointing to my answer, which has many issues left): [Pointer Dequeue - pointer training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947177/pointer-dequeue-pointer-training/39947724#39947724)

Anyways:

Do you want to return int or float? The element data is type float, your variable "number" too, but your function returns int.

```
int pop_front(list** header)
{
  float number = (*header)->data;
```

so, here you get the value of the element you're trying to remove, but then ...

```
  list *head = *header;
  list *remove = head;

  // This should check if the pointer is pointing at the first element
  while (head->prev != NULL) {
    head = head->prev;
  }
```

... you actually SEARCH for the element to remove.

Obviously, you have to do it the other way round:

```
int pop_front(list** header)
{
    list * head = *header;
    while (head->prev) head = head->prev;
```

now, you should check, weather you need to adjust the *header pointer (and do it right away):

```
    if (*header == head) {
        *header = head->next;
    }
```

the only thing to do now is to remove the object from the list, get it's value and free it's memory before return.

```
    head->next->prev = NULL;
    float retval = head->data;
    free(head);
    return retval;
}
```

As exercise left to you: Make sure, that an empty list doesn't crash ;)

/edit: This will also crash for removal of the last element, so you have two exercises left ;)

Comment: one easy question can i make *header = NULL; in c ?

Comment: when i take the last element out.

Comment: yes. "*header" is the object, that "header" points to and since it is not const you can assign a value to it. NULL is a value. So you can assign NULL.